# I can't get back()->withInput() to work, the documentation seems a little sparse on how it should work

Tags: laravel

I'm using blade templates and this is how my form looks:

```
        <form action="{{ route("user-sessions.store") }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="e-mail">E-mail Address</label>
                <input name="email_address" class="form-control" type="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input name="password" class="form-control" type="password" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Does `back()->withInput()` only work with `{{ Form::open() }}`? If so, the 7.x documentation doesn't say that it seems. I would think if you need a 3rd party library to get this to work, the documentation should say so. If that's not the issue, then what am I doing wrong?

I'm using Laravel 7.x.

Comment: considering the Form Builder you are referring to isn't something that comes with Laravel, no it isn't required ... what are you expecting `withInput` to do?

Comment: I was thinking it would repopulate the form fields, the docs don't seem to say how this is accomplished.

Comment: because you do that yourself, you are writing the html there, you have to check for old inputs and set the value of the field appropriately

Comment: "To retrieve flashed input from the previous request, use the old method" Docs pretty good I would say. e.g. value="{{ old('username') }}"

Comment: @jewishmoses https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#redirects -- I think here it should say "puts the input into the session object" so that you know you need to retrieve it.

Comment: @BlaineLafreniere https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#old-input

Comment: @jewishmoses yeah I see that, but that's not where I first read about it. The link I posted isn't clear.

Comment: @BlaineLafreniere you could have a point there; the docs are open to PRs https://github.com/laravel/docs

Comment: @lagbox alright, I'll consider making a contribution :p

Answer (score 0):

if you use html collective, it automatically puts old values in form inputs. But when use pure html to create form inputs you have to use `old` method for input values. like this:

```
<form action="{{ route("user-sessions.store") }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="e-mail">E-mail Address</label>
                <input name="email_address" class="form-control" type="email" value="{{old('email_address')}}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input name="password" class="form-control" type="password" value="{{old('password')}}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
```